# Nvidia Quadro t400,t600,t1000 compatibility with ASUS prime h610M-E D4 Motherboard

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I have a PC with these parts:

- [Asus Prime H610M-E D4 Motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-H610M-E-D4/)
- Intel i5 12400F processor

Are these graphics cards compatible with it?

- Nvidia Quadro T400
- Nvidia Quadro T600
- Nvidia Quadro T1000

Answer (score 0):

If those GPU's use PCIe 16x (most do), totally yes. You may want to install OpenCL drivers though if you want to do a bit more than just using it as screen output (which I do sometimes with my quadro)

Comment: How good is Nvidia Quadro T400 for 3d designing softwares like Solidworks

Comment: I really don't know, I have not seen any benchmarks of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those Quadro cards will be compatible with your system.

For 3D design, I would recommend just getting a cheaper card on a price-to-performance comparison. Here is a good chart for the current prices: https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_value.html

I would go with the [6500 XT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09PSHYHLM), but feel free to take a look at the chart and choose for yourself. The 6500 XT has more VRAM and is cheaper than the Quadro T400.

I have found that VRAM is the biggest difference in my 3D work, but it doesn't need to be the biggest and best card on the market. I also find AMD cards play a lot nicer than Nvidia if you need to switch to Linux to run certain simulations.